# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLength()

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Firstly i was getting an error in

```
php artisan migrate
```

as

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

and Then i found a post on `laracasts` to fix this as

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

After adding this, when i run

```
php artisan optimize
```

then i am presented with new error as below

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLength()`

Please assist in getting rid of all these errors.

Comment: What is your laravel version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defaultStringLength` is introduced in Laravel v5.4. [Reference](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error).

You can update the Laravel version

OR

You specify the length as `$table->string('coumname', 255);` You cannot specify more than `255`. If you leave the length parameter it will assign `255` by default

Answer (score 1):

This is because Laravel 5.4 uses the utf8mb4 character set by default, which includes support for storing “emojis” in the database. You can choose any one from these 2 solutions:

1) Change

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

2) Edit AppServiceProvider located at App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php and add the following line to the boot() method and load the Schema facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
* Bootstrap any application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

What that will do is actually change the default maximum field length in the database and actually shorten your maximum string length from 255 to maximum of 191 characters (utf8 uses 3 bytes per character while utf8mb4 uses 4 bytes per character your field can now hold 25% less characters 255 * 75% = 191.25). So if you don’t set the string field by hand in the migration the new default will be 191.

Answer (score 0):

Find AppServiceProvider in Laravel Project

1.First Add Facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

2.Add Below lines in boot function

```
function boot() {
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; to your AppServiceProvider.php file in App/Providers folder.
2. Add Schema::defaultStringLength(191); to the boot function.

Answer (score -1):

If Laravel < 5.4
 1. Find AppServiceProvider in Laravel Project
 2. Comment line or remove Schema::defaultStringLength(191) in boot method