# Laravel Failing on php artisan migrate after php artisan make:auth

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, authentication

I decided to test the new Laravel. So I started with the basic commands:

```
$ laravel new blog

$ php artisan make:auth

$ php artisan migrate
```

and I edited my AppServiceProvider.php file and add to the boot method a default string length

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

But I still have an error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLength()
```

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @AguDondo Laravel 5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLength()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105351/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-schema-mysqlbuilderdefaultstringl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defaultStringLength` was introduced in Laravel 5.4.

[Reference](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)

Comment: Ok, but how to work registration without defaultStringLength,
it don't work and don't insert data in users table. @AguDondo

Comment: I upgraded laravel 5.2 to to 5.4 , but i still have same error @AguDondo

Answer (score 1):

in app/providers
open AppServiceProviders

in boot function

```
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

and add the following class on the top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Although it is not necessary to use in laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong class. The class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema does not have method defaultStringLength, but insted the class Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder does it.
check the docs:
[MySqlBuilder Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.html#method_defaultStringLength)
[Schema Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Schema.html)

Comment: when i add the class Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder  instead of  The class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema, i had an error  the Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found

Answer (score 0):

This is because Laravel 5.4 uses the utf8mb4 character set by default, which includes support for storing “emojis” in the database. You can choose any one from these 2 solutions:

1) Change

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

2) Edit AppServiceProvider located at App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php and add the following line to the boot() method and load the Schema facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
* Bootstrap any application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

What that will do is actually change the default maximum field length in the database and actually shorten your maximum string length from 255 to maximum of 191 characters (utf8 uses 3 bytes per character while utf8mb4 uses 4 bytes per character your field can now hold 25% less characters 255 * 75% = 191.25). So if you don’t set the string field by hand in the migration the new default will be 191.